# Add BitmapField to TreeField

Tags: blackberry, treeview, bitmap

In BlackBerry is it possible to add an image to child nodes of a TreeField?
If yes can any one please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Like a ListField, a TreeField is not a subclass of Manager so you can't 'add' other fields to it. The TreeField manages the expansion, contraction user input and informs your application what neeeds to be drawn by invoking:

```
net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TreeFieldCallback.drawTreeItem(TreeField treeField, Graphics graphics, int node, int y, int width, int indent)
```

Your application is then responsible for drawing what should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

possible

use

```
g.drawBitmap(...);
```

inside the

```
TreeFieldCallback.drawTreeItem(TreeField treeField, Graphics graphics, int node, int y, int width, int indent)
```

method